# ThreadPoolExecutor and join()

Tags: java, multithreading, join, executorservice

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor in SomeService to perform some work on data. The problem is SomeServiceTest completes before work threads scheduled into ThreadPoolExecutor complete. I want SomeService thread to be joined with work threads. Is there any way to join parent thread with work thread at the moment executor starts it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to do this?

```
 executorService.shutdown();
 executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOUR);
```